# Font with Dollars but no line through it

Tags: fonts, font-encodings

Is there a font with a dollar sign that only has the parts of the line above and below the S?  Adobe says it is Univers but that $ doesnt match.

Answer (score 14):

TeX Gyre Adventor (similar to Avantgarde)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tgadventor}
\begin{document}
\textsf{\$}
\end{document}
```

> [image: TeX Gyre Adventor]

Only the symbol without changing the whole sans-serif font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\mydollar}{%
  \begingroup\fontfamily{qag}\$\endgroup
}
\begin{document}
\mydollar
\end{document}
```

Version for LuaTeX/XeTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\tgadventor{TeX Gyre Adventor}
\newcommand*{\mydollar}{%
  \begingroup\tgadventor\$\endgroup
}
\begin{document}
\mydollar
\end{document}
```

### Small font overview

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\def\x#1{%
  #1:& \fontspec{#1}\$\\
}
\begin{tabular}{l@{ }l}
\x{TeX Gyre Adventor}
\x{TeX Gyre Chorus}
\x{Source Code Pro}
\x{Source Sans Pro}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 6):

Some Sans and Monospace font have it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Roboto}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Ubuntu}
\begin{document}

\textsf{\$}\texttt{\$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Some possibilities: Calibri, Candara, Courier, Courier CE, Courier New, Futura, Gr Plain, Impact, Kino MT, Kohinoor, KohinoorBangla, Lithos Pro Regular, Myriad Pro, Myriad Pro Cond, Myriad Pro Light, Playbill, Prestige Elite Std Bold, Roboto, Seravek, Skia, TeX Gyre Adventor, TeX Gyre Cursor.

Many of these fonts are OpenType; you'll need to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX along with the `fontspec` package to make use of them.

Comment: It is worth noting that several are type1 and supported by (pdf)LaTeX packages.

Answer (score 4):

You can answer this kind of questions with [Identifont](http://www.identifont.com/). On the front page, in the “Fonts by Appearance” tab, click “Limited set of letters?”. Type `$` and choose the desired appearance for that character. Identifont knows of [4448 such fonts](http://www.identifont.com/identify?2+$+1QZ). You then get a list of “popular” matching fonts, and you can further refine the list by describing other characteristics of the font. Identifont asks the questions in a predefined order but you can skip some questions by clicking “Not Sure”.

A limitation of this approach is that there's no filter for things like “available on my TeX installation” or “available for free”.